# How to make copy initialization private in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-constructor

In the following simplification of a real-world example, the intention is to enforce that a user of class `A` can only obtain temporary references to its objects (in my actual example, the class `A` is a proxy class used to overload operators on the return values of other classes):

```
struct A {
    static A foo() {
        return A();
    }
private:
    A() {}
    A(const A&) = default;
};

int main() {
    A a = A::foo();
}
```

I therefore expect the assignment to `a` to fail, and this is indeed what happens in C++14 and earlier:

```
main.cpp:11:11: error: calling a private constructor of class 'A'
    A a = A::foo();
          ^
main.cpp:7:5: note: declared private here
    A(const A&) = default;
    ^
```

However, in C++17, this is not an error since, because there is no assignment happening, rather `a` is merely being copy initialized. In this case, how can I enforce the previous semantics? Is there a way to declare copy initialization of `A` to be private as well (preferably without modifying the return type of foo)?

Comment: Why would you want this? I think this is a XY-problem.

Comment: "rather `a` is merely being copy initialized" I think the copy is elided, in C++17.

Comment: For your underlying problem, r-value qualify method might do what you want `void A::Bar()&&;`.

Comment: `A a = A::foo();` -- this has always been copy construction; it has never been assignment. The rule used to be that the copy constructor had to be available, even if the copy was elided. But now, God knows, anything goes. (with apologies to Cole Porter)

Comment: `static A const& foo() { static A a; a = A(); return a; }`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The entire point of guaranteed elision is to make it so that `A a = A::foo();` doesn't do any copying. Ever. Even hypothetically. And the point of that is to be able to have factory functions even for types that cannot be copied/moved.

C++17 and above do not allow you the power to deny someone the ability to use a factory function for your type, so long as their code complies with the rules of guaranteed elision.